# How do I skip the first piece of data when extracting from a csv file with PHP

Tags: php, csv, extract

The following code is what I am using to get an entire column of data from my csv files. (There are many columns, but I only need #2). This code will put all of the data into the array called `$cbsmin`.  What I need to do is skip the very first piece of data in each file as it is the category name not actually a piece of data.

How would this best be done?

```
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    if (($handle = fopen($files[$i], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            $cbsmin[] = $data[2];

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a simple flag to mark if it is the first line. If it is, reset the flag to false and skip that line.

```
$isfirst = true;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($isfirst)
    {
        $isfirst = false;
        continue;
    }
    $cbsmin[] = $data[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just execute a single

```
   fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
```

before the while loop.

Comment: Yes, this would be a better solution rather than writing this much piece of code. Why write extra lines if you get the desired solution by writing only just one line.

Answer (score 0):

Just throw in an extra read prior to going into the while loop

```
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    if (($handle = fopen($files[$i], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        // eat the header
        fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

            $cbsmin[] = $data[2];

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Another technique I use for this is to use the header row for keys in the data. This works if the header rows are consistent over time and from file to file.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($files);$i++){
    if (($handle = fopen($files[$i], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        // eat the header
        $header = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $data = array_combine($header, $data);
            $cbsmin[] = $data["Customer Name"];

        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

It beats having to use field offsets if you are doing anything non-trivial with a lot of the fields.